# random number generation in java with multiple of 1000 a number appear

Tags: java, random

I am looking to get random number in between 1000 to 8192000. The random number should be like 1000 , 2000,3000 to 8192000.

Following is the code that i have tried but did not got any success.

```
ran.nextInt(8192000 - 1000)%1000;
```

What should I change in order to get number in term of 1000, 2000, 3000...

Comment: You ask about solution without your own code example to show some efforts

Comment: "Did not get any success" is not a valid problem description. Looking at the output should reveal quite a simple difference between what is, and what is desired.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest approach would seem to generate a random number between 1 and 8192 and just multiply it by 1000:

```
Random randomGenerator = new Random();
long randomNumber = (1 + randomGenerator.nextInt(8192)) * 1000L;
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want 8192000 inclusive try:

```
Random random = new Random();
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  System.out.println((random.nextInt(8192) + 1) * 1000);
}
```

Here you get values: 1000, 2000, ..., 8192000